# Reposition squares diagonally with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, addeventlistener

I need to symmetrically reposition 5 squares by switching their left and top values. It's only in JavaScript, via the functions init() and reposition(). In init(), I have to call the function repositionner() when the mouser hovers on an element from the class square (so carre1 to carre5). In repositionner(), I must implement the code to switch squares horizontal value with their vertical value. I'm not sure if my code for init() works, but I definitely can't figure out repositionner(). Both functions are empty from the start. Thank you for your replies, here is my code :

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="fr">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Reposition the squares</title>
                <style>
                    #bac {
                        position: relative;
                        width: 400px;
                        height: 400px;
                        border: 1px solid red;
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                    .square {
                        width: 50px;
                        height: 50px;
                    }
                    #carre1 {
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 300px;
                        top: 200px;
                        background-color: red;
                    }
                    #carre2 {
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 120px;
                        top: 75px;
                        background-color: blue;
                    }
                    #carre3 {
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 50px;
                        top: 240px;
                        background-color: orange;
                    }
                    #carre4 {
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 350px;
                        top: 0px;
                        background-color: black;
                    }
                    #carre5 {
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 50px;
                        top: 50px;
                        background-color: pink;
                    }
                </style>
                <script>
                    function init() { <!-- code here -->
                         for(let i = 0 ; i < document.getElementsByClassName("square").length; i++){
                document.getElementsByClassName("square")[i].addEventListener("mouseover",reposition);
            }
                    }
            
                    function reposition() { <!-- code here -->
            
                        document.getElementById("carre1").style.top = "300px";
                        document.getElementById("carre1").style.left = "200px";
            
            
                        document.getElementById("carre2").style.top="120px";
                        document.getElementById("carre2").style.left="75px";
            
                        document.getElementById("carre3").style.top="50px";
                        document.getElementById("carre3").style.left="240px";
            
                        document.getElementById("carre4").style.top="350px";
                        document.getElementById("carre4").style.left="0px";
            
                        document.getElementById("carre5").style.top="50px";
                        document.getElementById("carre5").style.left="50px";
            
                    }
            
            
                </script>
            </head>
            <body onload="init()">
            <h1>Reposition the squares</h1>
            <div id="bac">
                <div id="carre1" class="square"></div>
                <div id="carre2" class="square"></div>
                <div id="carre3" class="square"></div>
                <div id="carre4" class="square"></div>
                <div id="carre5" class="square"></div>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this is a sufficient solution for you. The issue with your `function init()` is that `document.getElementsByClassName('.square')` returns an html collection so you need to loop over the squares to add an `addEventListener`. I did that here with a `forEach` loop. Also there was an issue with the placement of the script tags, I moved them to the bottom of the page as I was getting errors that about locating elements on the page.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="fr">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Reposition the squares</title>
            <style>
                #bac {
                    position: relative;
                    width: 400px;
                    height: 400px;
                    border: 1px solid red;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                .square {
                    width: 50px;
                    height: 50px;
                }
                #carre1 {
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 300px;
                    top: 200px;
                    background-color: red;
                }
                #carre2 {
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 120px;
                    top: 75px;
                    background-color: blue;
                }
                #carre3 {
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 50px;
                    top: 240px;
                    background-color: orange;
                }
                #carre4 {
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 350px;
                    top: 0px;
                    background-color: black;
                }
                #carre5 {
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 50px;
                    top: 50px;
                    background-color: pink;
                }
            </style>
               
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Reposition the squares</h1>
        <div id="bac">
            <div id="carre1" class="square"></div>
            <div id="carre2" class="square"></div>
            <div id="carre3" class="square"></div>
            <div id="carre4" class="square"></div>
            <div id="carre5" class="square"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
          document.querySelectorAll('.square').forEach(square => square.addEventListener('mouseover', reposition));
        
            function reposition() { <!-- code here -->

                document.getElementById("carre1").style.top = "300px";
                document.getElementById("carre1").style.left = "200px";

                document.getElementById("carre2").style.top="120px";
                document.getElementById("carre2").style.left="75px";

                document.getElementById("carre3").style.top="50px";
                document.getElementById("carre3").style.left="240px";

                document.getElementById("carre4").style.top="350px";
                document.getElementById("carre4").style.left="0px";

                document.getElementById("carre5").style.top="50px";
                document.getElementById("carre5").style.left="50px";

            }

        </script>
        </body>
        </html>

Expand snip
```

Comment: I solved the problem for init() by doing                                                                            
             for(let i = 0 ; i < document.getElementsByClassName("square").length; i++){
                document.getElementsByClassName("square")[i].addEventListener("mouseover",reposition); } but it still doesn't solve reposition. Currently, when I hover on a square, all of them move instead of one. Reposition() needs a fix but I don't know what to do.